# How to copy from one variable to another on SPSS

Tags: spss

I have a data set with two parent/carer respondents (main and partner) for each participant (child). For one of the variables, only one respondent has given an answer - usually the main respondent, but in some cases it was the partner respondent. I therefore need to fill in some missing main respondent data with data from the partner respondent.

My data looks roughly like this:

```
MAIN                PARTNER              I would like the final var as below:
2                   -1                      2
1                   -1                      1
-1                   2                      2
1                    .                      1
-9                   2                      2
-8                   1                      1
2                    .                      2
1                    .                      1
etc.
```

(-1, -8 and -9 are missing values)

All variables are numeric. Where a response is missing from the main respondent, I would like to fill it in from the partner. I cannot seem to get the DO IF/RECODE commands to work.

Any advice on how to do this in SPSS would be hugely appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More than one way to skin a cat. Depending on your taste, you might create your final variable `responder` like so:

```
MISSING VALUES main (-1,-8,-9) .
IF (MISSING(main)) responder=partner .
IF (NOT(MISSING(main))) responder=main .
EXE .
```

First assign your missing values. Then assign a value to `responder` based on whether `main` is missing. Note that `MISSING(main)` will evaluate true when main has a specified missing value (in this case: -1, -8, or -9) or a system missing value.

Comment: Thank you so much, this was a huge help!

Comment: No problem @AmeliaM. -- happy to help!  If you feel it answered your question please consider selecting it (using the check mark next to the response)